# Is the iPhone 4+ displaying images 2x the size if your site doesn't have retina support?

Tags: iphone, html, css, image

I just started reading about Retina Display on the iphone 4+ and I would like to know if right now all these iphones4+ are displaying images 2x the normal size on web pages if you don't have a the imagefilename@2x.extension ?!

This would be a huge headache if I have to wrote all that extra code like media queries and add @2x after every background images...

If so, what are your swiftest solution? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file name has nothing to do with your web site. You can name your image files anything you want. The '@2x' is just an informal standard many use for retina web images. If you want retina images to be used, you can use the media query to swap out the images via CSS with the higher resolution versions.

http://benfrain.com/how-to-serve-high-resolution-website-images-for-retina-displays-new-ipadiphone4/

Comment: Oh, so that means that I don't HAVE to create extra set of images for retina support right? It's just a nice option for the iphone if it's there. If not, then the images renders the same (in dimensions and all) on it as it would on any other similar mobile device.

Comment: Right. You don't have to make separate high-res images. They look a bit sharper for those that do have Retina, but it's not a requirement by any means...your regular images will render at the same normal size regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Mobile Safari interprets `px` as points and you therefore don't need to do anything for your app to work on a retina device.

If you want to provide high-res images though, wrap it in a CSS media query:

```
@media all and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:2) {
    #id {
        background-image: url(background@2x.png);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
}
```